# Nach "dem" oder ohne dem

Tags: grammaticality

Folgender Satz hat eine reghafte Diskussion unter Kollegen ausgelöst:

> Das Dokument wird nach dem Überschreiten des Ablaufdatums in den
>   Papierkorb verschoben!

Anlass dazu ist das kleine Wörtchen `dem`.

Ich bin der Meinung, es kann getrost weggelassen werden. Entspringen meine Gedanken lediglich dem Trend zur Faulheit oder ist der Satz ohne `dem` grammatikalisch tatsächlich korrekt?

Answer (score 6):

Dies ist keine Frage der Grammatik sondern eine des Stils.

Beide Varianten sind möglich und akzeptabel. Es kommt vor allem auf den Kontext an.

> Das Dokument wird nach dem Überschreiten des Ablaufdatums in den Papierkorb verschoben!

wäre die "normale" Form für diesen Satz.

> Das Dokument wird nach Überschreiten des Ablaufdatums in den Papierkorb verschoben!

hat eine etwas bürokratischere, strengere, amtlichere Anmutung, wird in diesem Biotop aber vermutlich häufiger anzutreffen sein als die Form mit "dem".

> Dokument wird nach Überschreiten des Ablaufdatums in Papierkorb verschoben!

wäre eine extreme Variante bürokratisch-kanzleimäßiger Ausdrucksweise. Wohingegen

> <strike>Dokument wird nach Überschreiten Ablaufdatums in Papierkorb verschoben!</strike>

auch in der bürokratischsten Behörde nicht mehr durchgehen wird. Offenbar können nur Artikel für Nominativ- und Akkusativ-Nomen weggelassen werden. Denkbar wäre wohl noch

> Dokument wird nach Ablaufdatum in Papierkorb verschoben!

Zum Kontrast:

> Das Kind wird nach dem Fernsehkucken ins Bett gebracht.

Hier kann man "dem" auf keinen Fall weglassen. Ich weiß auch nicht recht, warum. Vielleicht einfach, weil das kein Inhalt ist, der typischerweise in Amtsstuben vorkommt?

Answer (score 2):

Es ist auf jeden Fall beides richtig. Ohne *dem* ist es aus meiner Sicht besser, aber das liegt daran, dass der Satz offensichtlich aus einem technischen Text stammt.

> nach dem Überschreiten des Ablaufdatums
>   nach der Überschreitung des Ablaufdatums
>   nach dem Ablauf des Verfallsdatums

Diese Varianten sind auf Grund von allgemein gültigen Prinzipien der Grammatik korrekt. Denn man kann einen Nebensatz der Art "nachdem der Plöwak fertiggeplonzt ist" durch "nach dem Plonzen des Plöwak" oder "nach der Plonzung des Plöwak" ersetzen. Oder auch mal durch "nach der Plonzage/Plonzifizierung/Plonzifikation/... des Plöwak". Je nachdem, was es eben so an Substantivierungen des Verbs *plonzen* gibt.

> nach Überschreiten des Ablaufdatums
>   nach Überschreitung des Ablaufdatums
>   nach Ablauf des Verfallsdatums

Diese Varianten sind ebenso nach einem allgemein gültigen Prinzip korrekt. Denn man kann "nachdem der Plöwak fertiggeplonzt ist" auch durch "nach Plonzen des Plöwak" oder "nach Plonzung des Plöwak" ersetzen. Oder auch mal durch "nach Plonzage/Plonzifizierung/Plonzifikation/... des Plöwak". Allerdings scheint das Prinzip mir hier nicht ganz so grundlegend zu sein, sondern eher aus dem vorhergehenden abgeleitet nach dem Motto: Der bestimmte Artikel der Substantivierung versteht sich ja sowieso von selbst, und eigentlich ist das Substantiv hier - wie das Objekt beweist - ja eh ein verkapptes Verb, also lassen wir den Artikel doch einfach weg.

Dass es sich wohl um ein Weglassen handelt, können wir auch daran erkennen, dass es dann oft nicht möglich ist, wenn der bestimmte Artikel mit der Präposition zu einem Wort verschmilzt:

> zur Verkündung der frohen Botschaft
>   zur Unterscheidung von anderen
>   am Ausgang des 20. Jahrhunderts

Die Varianten mit *zu* bzw. *an* gehen hier nicht - wohl weil man dabei gegenüber der 'vollen' Version keine Silbe einspart. Ebenso geht das Weglassen des Artikels nicht, wenn das Substantiv nicht als Substantivierung eines transitiven Verbs inklusive angefügtem Objekt interpretiert werden kann:

> nach dem Kochen
>   nach dem Kochen der Suppe
>   nach Kochen der Suppe

Was hier nicht geht, ist "nach Kochen" ohne das Gekochte.

Obwohl die kürzere Variante wohl von der längeren abgeleitet ist - oder vielleicht gerade deswegen -, ist sie in technischen Texten meist die bessere, elegantere, idiomatischere. Unter den ersten drei Beispielen ist das vor allem bei *Ablauf* der Fall. *Nach Ablauf* ist ganz offensichtlich die normale Formulierung, und *nach dem Ablauf* ist selten.(Häufigkeit in gedruckten Texten ca. 1:20.) Da handelt es sich eben um eine feste Wendung, von der man normalerweise nicht ohne Grund abweicht. Nicht ganz so krass ist das bei *Überschreiten* (1:4) und *Überschreitung* (ca. 1:2; die Häufigkeit der selteneren Variante mit Artikel nimmt in letzter Zeit leicht zu).

PS: Christian Geiselmann findet, dass die kürzere Variante bürokratischer klingt. Dem kann ich nicht widersprechen. "Nach Kochen der Suppe" würde ich eher in einem Kochrezept oder einem Polizeibericht erwarten. "Nach dem Kochen der Suppe" ist eher die normale Version in einem Roman.

Allerdings ist aus meiner Sicht die in solchen technischen Texten häufigere (kürzere) Variante in diesem Kontext wohl auch die bessere, was ja für beliebte bürokratische Konstruktionen nicht immer der Fall ist.

Nachdem mir diese Kontextabhängigkeit klar wurde, habe ich meine Antwort ein bisschen überarbeitet.

Comment: Es muss aber heißen *nachdem der Plöwak fertiggeplonzt ist* - ohne Getrenntschreibung!

Answer (score 2):

Das kleine Wörtchen `dem` könnte darauf hindeuten, dass der Moment des Überschreitens bereits existiert und hinreichend genau bestimmt ist (daher auch der bestimmte Artikel). Das Weglassen drückt dann eine zukünftige Handlung aus, deren genauer Zeitpunkt eher unbestimmt ist.

Comment: Ein sinnreicher Gedanke. Allerdings: Mit dem alternativen Beispielsatz *Das Kind wird nach dem Fernsehkucken ins Bett gebracht* funktioniert es nicht recht, auch wenn ein zukünftiges Fernsehkucken unbestimmten Zeitpunkts gemeint ist.